# Swift - MacOS NSPasteboard - simultaneously support HTML and plain strings

Tags: html, swift, clipboard, nspasteboard

I have a use-case where I want my application to store clipboard data and later allow the user to paste it out.
The thing is - I want to both support HTML-styled text (while maintaining its styling) and also support simple plain-text.
What I have so far is:

- Pasteboard variable setup

```swift
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
pasteboard.declareTypes([.html, .string], owner: nil)
```

- Storing user's clipboard data

```swift
let copiedString = pasteboard.string(forType: .html) ?? pasteboard.string(forType: .string) {
```

  If, for example, a user copies text from the browser, this method maintains the entire HTML.
  Alternatively, if text is being copied from applications that don't support HTML (such as XCode, Notes, etc), `copiedString` will simply hold the plain text.

- Later down the line - pushing contents back to clipboard

```swift
pasteboard.setString(copiedString, forType: .html)
```

My problem is, when I try to paste the content pushed into my clipboard; it only works in **applications that actually support HTML-formatted text**, such as Chrome / Microsoft Word.
When I try to paste the content into XCode for example, it simply doesn't spit out anything.
Ideally, I want my clipboard to adjust itself according to the application I'm on - paste the text as HTML if supported by the application, otherwise - paste the plain text.

How can I implement such behavior?
Thanks!

Comment: You only have control over what you put on the pasteboard.  You have no control over which of the pasteboard representations you've offered the application you are pasting into will prefer.  Are you putting both representations on the pasteboard?

Comment: @ScottThompson Thanks for your reply. I don't fully understand what you mean. If I always use `forType: .string` I would be able to paste across all applications, but my original content's format (e.g. size, bullets etc) would be lost. If I always use `.html` - I wouldn't be able to paste in apps that don't support HTML content. Is there a way to push both representation into the clipboard using the `setString` method above?

Comment: A pasteboard can store many representations of the same item.  You could represent the item as HTML and as plaintext simultaneously.  You could also generate an image for the item and put it on there too.  When the receiving application pastes it can choose which representation it wants. So yes, you should be able to use `setString` to give an HTML and a plaintext representation simultaneously.

Comment: @ScottThompson I see, thanks! Didn't realize that using the `setString` method you could actually provide values for multiple types simultaneously without them overwriting each other.

Comment: Just FYI, your pasteboard can also contain multiple items (each with multiple representations).   `setString` and most of the other routines (if you read the docs carefully) always change the first one.  (I can't remember how you add multiples... I think it was `[pasteboard writeObjects: array]` or something)